# MYSQLI Error : Call to a member function execute() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, html, css, mysqli

I am tring to setup an MYSQLI statement with an Inner Join that worked fine as a mysql_query, but now the SQL won't work.

I'm assuming I'm getting an non-object error because the SQL is not able to return successful.  Which I don't understand because all table columns names match perfectly, like I said it works as an old mysql_result, and we have MYSQLI working elsewhere on the page.  Could there be corruption to the table itself?

Error:

> Warning : mysqli.prepare() [mysqli.prepare]: Couldn't fetch mysqli in file.php on line 123
>
> Fatal Error : Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in file.php on line 123

Code:

```
<?php
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT A.ID, A.HEADER, A.CONTENT, A.PICTURE, A.CATEGORY_ID, C.ID, C.CATEGORY FROM ARTICLES A INNER JOIN ARTICLE_CATEGORY C ON A.CATEGORY_ID=C.ID ORDER BY C.CATEGORY, A.ID DESC");
$stmt->execute();
if ($stmt->bind_result($ID, $HEADER, $CONTENT, $PICTURE, $CATEGORY))
{
  ...
  ...

  while($stmt->fetch()) 
  {
    ...
    ...
    ...
  }
}
?>
```

Note: Coming from asp.net I'm very noob at mysqli but I'm fairly sure I'm not using the OO method.

I found the answer at this other slightly different case:
[Problem with mysqli fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526234/problem-with-mysqli-fetch)

But this answer required $stmt->store_result() with nested $stmt units, I just needed to clear them so prepare() could have working space.

Turns out the answer is that I was missing $stmt->free_result(); and $stmt->close(); Also for 3 loops on the one page the $stmt variable names need to be kept distinct ex: $stmt1, $stmt2, $stmt3

Comment: `$stmt->execute();` => `if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$db->error, E_USER_WARNING);}`

Comment: It seems there is more to the error, just above...Warning : mysqli.prepare() [mysqli.prepare]: Couldn't fetch mysqli in file.php on line 123    The $db->error does not process

Comment: The "couldn't fetch myusqli" error means that `$db` isn't a valid `mysqli` object. I suspect it's a scope problem.

Comment: If there are multiple $db objects on one page, do they need distinct names?  I have 3 loops on this one page to load content, and one so far using mysqli with no problem.

Comment: Turns out the answer is that I was missing               $stmt->free_result();   and 
$stmt->close();                                                                                       Also for 3 loops on one page the $stmt variable names need to be kept distinct ex: $stmt1, $stmt2, $stmt3